# Using command line gdal to open and convert OSM file to feature class

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

I have an file that is in the format `.osm.pbf`. It's about 8GB. I want to convert it to a feature class and place it in a file geodatabase. From what I can see, the simplest way to do that is using `gdal` and `ogr2ogr`. I had both installed with my OSGeo/QGIS. The `gdal` and `ogr2ogr` package files and executables are in my `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin` folder. Initially, I tried converting to a `shapefile` but ran into problems. I tried running the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" mydata.shp mydata.osm.pbf
```

I immediately got the following error messages:

```
Warning 1: Cannot find osmconf.ini configuration file
ERROR 1: Could not parse configuration file for OSM import
FAILURE:Unable to open datasource `na_test.osm.pbf' with the following drivers.
  -> `JP2ECW'
  -> `OCI'
  ...
  -> `OSM'
```

I see that I have an 'OSM' driver, but it seems that either a) I don't have `osmconf.ini` or its in the wrong spot, or b) I need to configure something in `osmconf.ini` so that it can open a `.osm.pbf` file. I do have a `osmconf.ini`, but its in my `C:\OSGeo4W64\share` folder. I tried copying it and placing it in 'bin`but that didn't seem to do any good. My system variable path is pointing to 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin`. In addition to this, I realized that there is no way I am converting 8GB +  `osm` files into a `shapefile` and I need to convert them to feature classes or geojson if possible. Help, is there a way to do this? Is ther something wrong with my gdal configuration?

**Side Note:** I do have gdal and ogr2ogr working in a `Python 3.x` environment with `Pandas/Geopandas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should find the osmconf.ini local to the installation.
You can override it using `-oo CONFIG_FILE=<yourpath>/osmconf.ini` on the command line.

You are probably also going to want to adjust your osmconf.ini to specify what is imported and what ignored. Also, how to handle closed ways,etc.

Yes shapefiles would be a bad choice. As would GeoJSON. You think PBF is big? This is a compressed binary format: Wait until you see a GeoJSON equivalent!

You could look at spatialite as one alternative. Also if you are serious about 8GB compressed files, then PostGIS should be seriously considered. Of course it all depends on what you are trying to do with the data.

Also note that the data is going to be imported with one 'layer' for each geometry type (point, linestring, etc) and not by feature type (road, river, etc).

Comment: you wrote "You are probably also going to want to adjust your osmconf.ini to specify what is imported and what ignored. Also, how to handle closed ways,etc". So, how would I do that? Specifically for a.pbf file? In the `osmconfig.ini` file, I see it is broken down by geometry type and that there are attribute keys, unsignificant keys, etc...but I really have no idea how to configure any of this. Suggestions?

Comment: Yes. I think you need to read up on OpenStreetMap data and how it is structured. Their website is a good start, eg: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners_Guide_1.3  Note it doesn't matter if you are using their native XML (which might be easier to think of) or the more opaque PBF - these structure the data in the same way. I think first you should try looking at a smaller data file. This will give you an idea of what the data looks like. Perhaps try QGIS or JOSM to have a look at a small section?

Comment: I think that needs to be -oo CONFIG_FILE=<yourpath>/osmconf.ini instead of -o